# why string variable "sum" is not storing any data and program is not giving any output

Tags: c++

```
    int l, s, j, k, carry=0;
    string num1, num2, sum;

    cin >> num1 >> num2;
    l = num1.size();
    s = num2.size();

    for(j=l-1; j>=0; j--)
    {
        k = (num1[j]-'0') + (num2[j]-'0') + carry;
        cout << k<<endl;
        carry = k/10;
        k%=10;
        sum[j]= '0' + k;
    }

    cout  << sum << endl;
```

I am trying to add two numbers(both have same digit length) using strings. It is not giving any output.

Answer (score 4):

Just after the variable declaration your `sum` variable is an empty string. You're trying to access `j`th element of it - this is the array index overflow and is an undefined behavior.

The solution is to initialize your string with something or use concatenate instead of changing the character, like this:

```
sum += (char)('0' + k);
```

**UP**: Such fix will write the result to the string in the reversed order, so, to obtain the correct string, you should also add

```
std::reverse(sum.begin(), sum.end());
```

after the loop.

And also, your code assumes that the `sum` length is exactly the same as the lengths of both arguments which may be wrong.

Comment: Don't you thing you will write the result number in reverse order if you use string concatenation that way?